# Expanding Perc 6/E Raid 6 while in use - Can this cause data loss?

Tags: raid6, perc6

There seems to be a lot of information on the 6/i controller but not 6/E. The Dell manual has bit of information on converting from one raid level to another but it does not specifically answer my question. Also, in researching this I saw a post for a completely different controller state that With Raid 5 (different raid level I know) you can only expand one disk at a time as the raid 5 will only tolerate one degraded disk.

My questions...

One PERC 6/E:

1. Can the Raid 6 array be expanded while it is in use without causing data loss?
2. Is expanding an array like causing it to be degraded? Do I need to expand the Raid array one disk at a time and definitely no more than 2 disks?
3. Are there any tricks, or traps to avoid?

I would sure hate to mess this up as it is the first time I have attempted this.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, I have done this. Worked without issues.
2. I think so. And it takes a really long to finish the operation. (I added one disk to a 8-disk R6 array, and it took about two days to complete)
3. I do not have anything to add about this.